# What is (the length of) the longest string that has no $k$ contiguous repeat substrings?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, ramsey-theory

I'm not sure if "concatenated" or "contiguous" is the better word here, or what the best way of phrasing it is, so let me give an example.

Consider strings of $\ 0'$s and $\ 1'$s, such as $\ '1000110101'.$ What is (the length, $n,$ of) the longest string that has no $k$ contiguous repeat substrings? For example, for $k=2,\ $ we are not allowed any substrings to repeat more than once. So, $\ '110'\ $ would fail, as it contains the substring $\ '11' = \,'1' + \,'1'.\ $ And $\ '10101'\ $ would fail, as it contains the substring $\ '1010' = \,'10' + \,'10'.\ $ So the longest substrings for $k=2$ are $\,'101'$ or $\,'010'$, and so for $k=2,$ our longest string has length $n=3.$

However, for $k=3,$ things already get seemingly wild: I think $\,'11011010110110'$ doesn't fail, and we can append many more $0's$ and $1's$ to the end before it fails.

> What is the largest value of $n$ for a given $k$?

Is this a known problem? If not, can we make any progress on it?

I am not asking for [de Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Examples), although these might be related to my question somehow.

Comment: See the [Thue Morse word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence).

Comment: Didn't 110 repeat in your example?

Comment: @kodlu It didn't repeat $3$ times consecutively (concatenated). If it did, it would have contained $\,'110110110'$.

Comment: @lulu are you saying that the Thue–Morse sequence is an infinite sequence that doesn't repeat?

Comment: It says on wikipedia: "$T$ contains no cubes: instances of $ XXX$." Why is this?

Comment: The Thue Morse word is an example of an  infinite cube free binary string.  I don't believe a good count is known for cube free binary strings of length $n$.

Comment: [here's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61373/cube-free-infinite-binary-words) a general discussion of infinite cube free binary words with some links.